# docker native networking vs weave net/flux/show

Tags: docker, weave

Want to know if waeve products are in sync with what docker is to offer.
Should i go with Native networking of Docker or with weave or both; (given that the docker networking space is constantly changing)
Please let me know the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Weaveworks products are continuously improved to work with bleeding edge versions of Docker and Kubernetes, as per the various [GitHub repositories](https://github.com/weaveworks).
2. Your question about "native Docker network" vs. "Weave Net" is a rather broad, and for it to be answered properly, you would need to share more details about what you want to achieve exactly.

   Feel free to detail your use case here so that the community can benefit from it, or if you do not want to do so publicly, to reach out to someone from Weaveworks on [Slack](http://weave-community.slack.com/).
3. Finally, [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1polIS2pvjOxCZ7hpXbra68CluwOZybsP1IYfr-HrAXc) was shared at some point on Kubernetes' Slack and attempts to give an overview of various container networking solutions, so this may be relevant.

   However, beware potentially out-of-date information, keep in mind the "devil is in the details" so the reality may not be as simple as it would seem according to this document. All available solutions will have pros and cons, but will also be more suitable for some use-cases than others, so always, it is a question of trade-offs and YMMV.

I hope this helps.